# Adding dynamic text to AVMutableVideoComposition overlay

Tags: ios, swift, video

I am experimenting with AVMutableVideoComposition. My purpose is to add time to video (with seconds), so it should be dynamic.

How should I approach it? Should I add X layers (where X is count of seconds) to video with specific timeframe?

I am using swift.

Thanks

Comment: Possible better way: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/avsubtitleswriterOSX/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: But I want to overlay it physically, not via subtitles.